# Is that possible to mock a single method with Mockall?

Tags: rust, mocking

I want to mock a regular single method in the module scope (not a trait  or struct method), that will return a constant value, but I can't find any example in the docs.

Comment: that the closet thing to mock that i found until now : https://klau.si/blog/mocking-in-rust-with-conditional-compilation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, but the workarounds are pretty easy:
1) Turn your single free function into a static method of a struct, and mock the struct.
2) Put your single free function into a module, and mock the module (requires nightly).