# What patterns exist for mocking a single function while testing?

Tags: testing, rust, mocking, swizzling

I have a function generates a salted hash digest for some data. For the salt, it uses a random `u32` value. It looks something like this:

```rust
use rand::RngCore;
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::Hasher;

fn hash(msg: &str) -> String {
    let salt = rand::thread_rng().next_u32();

    let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
    s.write_u32(salt);
    s.write(msg.as_bytes());
    format!("{:x}{:x}", &salt, s.finish())
}
```

In a test, I'd like to validate that it produces expected values, given a known salt and string. How do I mock ([swizzle](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/right-way-to-swizzle/)?) `rand::thread_rng().next_u32()` in the test to generate a specific value? In other words, what could replace the comment in this example to make the test pass?

```rust
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_hashes() {
        // XXX How to mock ThreadRng::next_u32() to return 3892864592?
        assert_eq!(hash("foo"), "e80866501cdda8af09a0a656");
    }
}
```

Some approaches I've looked at:

- I'm aware that the [`ThreadRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) returned by `rand::thread_rng()` implements [`RngCore`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.RngCore.html), so [in theory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59566797/79202) I could set a variable somewhere to store a reference to a `RngCore`, and implement my own mocked variant to set during testing. I've taken this sort of approach in Go and Java, but I couldn't get the Rust type checker to allow it.
- I looked at the list of mock frameworks, such as [MockAll](https://github.com/asomers/mockall), but they appear to be designed to mock a struct or trait to pass to a method, and this code doesn't pass one, and I wouldn't necessarily want users of the library to be able to pass in a `RngCore`.
- Use the `#[cfg(test)]` macro to call a different function specified in the tests module, then have that function read the value to return from elsewhere. This I got to work, but had to use an unsafe mutable static variable to set the value for the mocked method to find, which seems gross. Is there a better way?

As a reference, I'll post an answer using the `#[cfg(test)]` + unsafe mutable static variable technique, but hope there's a more straightforward way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the links to dupes, @Shepmaster. I think, reading through those, I can eventually understand a Rust-ier way to go about it, I'm not fluent enough yet that they're super obvious. Your section on methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370712/79202) looks closest to what I imagine would be best; I'll work though its application to my example and post a link to a playground here once I'm happy with it.

Comment: Sounds good! You may also be interested in [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423) to avoid external API changes just to enable dependency injection for testing.

Answer (score 2):

In the test module, use [lazy-static](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) to add a static variable with a Mutex for thread safety, create a function like `next_u32()` to return its value, and have tests set the static variable to a known value. It should fall back on returning a properly random number if it's not set, so here I've made it `Vec<u32>` so it can tell:

```rust
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use lazy_static::lazy_static;
    use std::sync::Mutex;

    lazy_static! {
        static ref MOCK_SALT: Mutex<Vec<u32>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
    }

    // Replaces random salt generation when testing.
    pub fn mock_salt() -> u32 {
        let mut sd = MOCK_SALT.lock().unwrap();
        if sd.is_empty() {
            rand::thread_rng().next_u32()
        } else {
            let ret = sd[0];
            sd.clear();
            ret
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_hashes() {
        MOCK_SALT.lock().unwrap().push(3892864592);
        assert_eq!(hash("foo"), "e80866501cdda8af09a0a656");
    }
}
```

Then modify `hash()` to call `tests::mock_salt()` instead of `rand::thread_rng().next_u32()` when testing (the first three lines of the function body are new):

```rust
fn hash(msg: &str) -> String {
    #[cfg(test)]
    let salt = tests::mock_salt();
    #[cfg(not(test))]
    let salt = rand::thread_rng().next_u32();

    let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
    s.write_u32(salt);
    s.write(msg.as_bytes());
    format!("{:x}{:x}", &salt, s.finish())
}
```

Then use of the macros allows Rust to determine, at compile time, which function to call, so there's no loss of efficiency in non-test builds. It does mean that there's some knowledge of the tests module in the source code, but it's not included in the binary, so should be relatively safe. I suppose there could be a custom derive macro to automate this somehow. Something like:

```rust
    #[mock(rand::thread_rng().next_u32())]
    let salt = rand::thread_rng().next_u32();
```

Would auto-generate the mocked method in the tests module (or elsewhere?), slot it in here, and provide functions for the tests to set the value --- only when testing, of course. Seems like a lot, though.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6a7586cb0cef399d9f34adce3b33599).

Comment: [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)

Comment: [applied](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2104fdc60e01ae4e0a992293f424d5fb)

Comment: Have to admit I don't follow the application of the mutable singleton answer here, although [lazy-static](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) looks like it'd be a nice replacement for the unsafe stuff I have here. Curious what fluent Rustaceans would make of this macro approach, though.

Comment: Your `static mut MOCK_SALT` *is* a global mutable singleton. Using `lazy_static!` and a `Mutex` avoids the unsafety. In fact, your code is *probably introducing undefined behavior*, especially considering all tests are run in separate threads. This is why `unsafe` shouldn't be used lightly.

Comment: Updated to use `lazy_static!` and a `Mutex` for thread safety.